# Date converting confusion with angular material date picker and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, angular-material

I have a short question about a good solution to solve the following problem: I use Angular Material date picker to select a date on an application. This date then will be stored in the database. During this process it will be converted to UTC "automatically".

When I then read/load it from the database it will not be converted back to local date automatically, which will cause some issue.

Because I did not wrote any line of code to convert data from local date to UTC during the process of saving data on the database I was a little bit surprised that the other way round is not managed likewise (so "automatically" UTC will be converted to local date). What will I need to do/configure to have the UTC date "automatically" been converted to local date while I'm loading data from the database?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What will be your datatype in SQL Server ? Also does your all application and sql server is on same machine.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. datatype on SQL Server is datetime2. Application and SQL Server running on the same machine currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one problem with approach.

1. When you post data from Angular to API call. At that time It will post date in UTC value and if you look at date in post then it has Z at the end of it.
2. Now API will store that date to sql server. Now once it will store in SQL Server it has no information for timezone. For this you have to use DatetimeOffset datatype.

Another

Now when you read from SQL Server then it has no timezone info so it will read as it is and consider as localtime so it will display wrong value in UI.

Mostly you have to make decision when you read from DB and convert back to local and this the step you have to perform.

Comment: Thank you very much. The missing timezone information in the database was the issue. Changing the type to DatetimeOffset fixed it.